# Adding a safe fail option for missing input data

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I have an example function like this:

```
def obtain_value(input_value):
    return max(input_value, 5)
```

I would like to make a safe fail option when the input value passed is None or NaN. So instead of just throwing some exceptions, it should fail safely.

Comment: IIUC you can use [numpy.nanmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) but you need to pass it a list i.e. something like `return np.nanmax([input_value, 5])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` (as defined by numpy) is a valid, "infinite" number, so the comparison makes sense and won't throw a `TypeError`. If you want to avoid it, the best is to filter it beforehand:

```py
def obtain_value(input_value):
    if input_value in [np.NaN, None]: # or more value considered possible but undesirable
        return None # fail safe
    return max(input_value, 5)
```

If you expect more "exotic" types that will trigger an exception (`str` or other), the `try/except` solution from @Rutger is good.

Comment: `np.nan` is not "infinite", it is something not defined. For example `np.nan >= 0` returns `False`. If you need a float that acts as infinity, there is `np.inf` which would return `True` in this comparison. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try / except in your function. That way, the function will work even if None is passed as input. Or do you mean something else with fail safely?

```
def obtain_value(input_value):
    try:
        return max(input_value, 5)
    except TypeError:
        return
```

Or you can only execute it if an int or float is passed:

```
def obtain_value(input_value):
    if type(input_value) in [int, float]:
        return max(input_value, 5)
```